# Scikit-learn SelectFromModel - actually obtain the feature importance scores of underlying predictor

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I was trying to estimate the feature importance for the classification task I have at hand. What is important for me is to get specific numbers which represent importance of each feature, not just 'pick X features which are most important'.

Obvious choice was to use the tree-based methods which provide nice feature_importances_ method to obtain importance of each feature. But I wasn't satisfied with the results of the tree-base classifiers. I learned that SelectFromModel method is capable to eliminate not important features based on the importance score and successfully does that for SVM or Linear models as well.

I wonder, is there any way to obtain specific importance score from SelectFromModel for each feature instead of just getting a list of most important features?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the GitHub [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/feature_selection/from_model.py), I found this piece of code:

```
def _get_feature_importances(estimator):
    """Retrieve or aggregate feature importances from estimator"""
    importances = getattr(estimator, "feature_importances_", None)

    if importances is None and hasattr(estimator, "coef_"):
        if estimator.coef_.ndim == 1:
            importances = np.abs(estimator.coef_)

        else:
            importances = np.sum(np.abs(estimator.coef_), axis=0)

    elif importances is None:
        raise ValueError(
            "The underlying estimator %s has no `coef_` or "
            "`feature_importances_` attribute. Either pass a fitted estimator"
            " to SelectFromModel or call fit before calling transform."
            % estimator.__class__.__name__)

    return importances
```

Thus, if you're using a linear model, the code is simply using the model coefficients as the "importance scores".

You can do that by pulling the `coef_` attribute from the estimator that you passed into `SelectFromModel`.

Example:

```
sfm = SelectFromModel(LassoCV(), 0.25)
sfm.fit(X, y)
print(sfm.estimator_.coef_)  # print "importance" scores
```

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. Hence for linear models I can just normalize the coefficients to get a 'relative' importance.

Comment: No problem! I can see a justification for normalizing if you plan to experiment with multiple models and then build a relative importance from the normalized coefficients of these multiple models, but if you're just using one model, I don't see how it would matter whether you normalize or not. However, I would apply the absolute value to the coefficients because a negative coefficient is just as important as a positive one if their magnitudes are the same, but I think you already know that :)